# git ignore specific directory, absolute path or relative path

Tags: git

I'd like to ignore directory `bower_components`,

```
bower_components
~/bower_components
/usr/root/bower_components
```

absolute path and relative path, which one should be used?

for security, I set

```
*ower_components/
```

Comment: Specify the path relative to the root of your git directory. You only need to ignore paths which are inside the git repo, no need to ignore `~/bower_components` and `/usr/root/bower_components` (assuming your repo is not `/` or `~`)

Comment: Could you please transmit the succinct comment to answer for further reference. @LakshayGarg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify the path relative to the root of your git directory. For example, if this is what your git repo looks like

```
demo
├── .git
├── bower_components
|   └── ...
└── xyz
    └── bower_components
        └── ...
```

Your .gitignore would contain only `bower_components`. It will take care of both the directories present in root and xyz directories.

You only need to ignore paths which are inside the git repo, no need to ignore `~/bower_components`, `/usr/root/bower_components` or anything else outside the repo. (assuming your repo is not / or ~)

Comment: While the bottom line of this answer is correct ("it will take care of both the directories present in root and xyz directories") the opening statement is not ("You should specify the path relative to the root of your git directory"). You are not specifying paths *relative* to the root--you are simply specifying folder names under the root of your git directory.

Answer (score 4):

Actuality the correct .gitignore would be

```
bower_components/
```

That would ignore folders only (and not potential *files* named `bower_components`)
And that would ignore any `bower_components` folder at any depth in the Git repository.

Comment: take the example in the second answer, what if I want to exclude `demo/bower_components` but not `demo/xyz/bower_components` ?

Comment: @AvinashRaj Try `/*/bower_components`.